# better Java IPC@Linux tactic: (a) java.nio File API on /dev/shm or (b) JNI to shmctl(2)?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, ipc, shared-memory, jna

We want write a Java 7 program that will boot (via 2 cmd line invokes) as two separate JVM process instances.  We want these 2 processes to communicate with each other using native Linux kernel shared-memory  IPC resources.

Does anyone have any insight as to which of these 2 approaches may have more merit?

1. Use java.nio.* API on /dev/shm
2. Use JNI bridge to C++ code that makes native shmctl() system calls

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vote "NIO and /dev/shm".

But before making any final decisions, you should also consider other options, including CLIP:

- http://ambientideas.com/blog/index.php/tag/java/page/2/
- http://ltsllc.com/talks/20090407_ipc.pdf
- [inter jvm communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810212/inter-jvm-communication)

Sockets, message queues and named pipes are other IPC methods I wouldn't necessarily dismiss out-of-hand.  IMHO...